# Spring request scope bean proxy bean can not be injected

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have a proxied request scope bean like this:

```
@Component
@Scope(value="request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@Lazy
public class AnyBean {
...
}
```

I want to have it injected into a service class:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AnyService {
    @Autowired
    private AnyBean anyBean;
}
```

When I start my application and or my integration tests, then it won't start. Application looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCommonsPersistenceAutoConfguration
@ImportResource({
   ....
})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class ApplicationTest {
...
}
```

The error I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'anyBean': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributesScope.get(AbstractRequestAttributesScope.java:41)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    ... 62 more
```

What I checked:

- Annotation processing is enabled, otherwise AnyService would not instantiate at all
- AnyBean is not final
- Request scope is defined in AnyBean along with the AspectJ Proxy (ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
- EnableAspectJAutoProxy annotation is present
- The following jars are on the classpath:

  D:\Users\liptak.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\xxx\aspectjweaver-xxx.jar
  D:\Users\liptak.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjrt\xxx\aspectjrt-xxx.jar
  D:\Users\liptak.m2\repository\cglib\cglib\xxx\cglib-xxx.jar
  D:\Users\liptak.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\xxx\asm-xxx.jar
  D:\Users\liptak.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\xxx.RELEASE\spring-aop-xxx.RELEASE.jar
  D:\Users\liptak.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\xxx\aopalliance-xxx.jar
  D:\Users\liptak.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\xxx.RELEASE\spring-aspects-xxx.RELEASE.jar

So it seems, that everything should be fine. Still it does not work. Do you have any ideas to check? Which Spring class would you debug?

### UPDATE:

Web XML contains RequestContextListener as well:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

### UPDATE 2:

When I add a breakpoint to org.springframework.aop.config.ScopedProxyBeanDefinitionDecorator.decorate(Node, BeanDefinitionHolder, ParserContext), it is not triggered at all.

Comment: Did you read the message?  Does any of the following apply? ***No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.***

Comment: @JimGarrison: Maybe I undestand it wrong. I thought, if I have a proxied request scope bean which I inject into my service, then a proxy will be actually injected, and upon a call to this proxy, the proxy will look for the request context in the thread and it will take care of instantiation. However in my case the injection itself does not work. The proxy seems not to be created at all.

Comment: @GáborLipták, can you provide full stack trace?

Comment: I suggest you write your own answer, transferring the solution description to there. Then you can accept your own answer so as to close the question. It might also help others that way.

Comment: @kriegaex done. Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

Solution is that my spring context is messed up a bit. AnyBean is not instantiated based on the annotation processing. I have found it in an XML config, where it is created directly like this:

```
<bean id="anyBean" class="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.AnyBean"  scope="request" lazy-init="true"/>
```

As soon as I change it like this, it works:

```
<bean id="anyBean" class="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.AnyBean"  scope="request" lazy-init="true">
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
</bean>
```

I *love* when annotation and xml based config is mixed up :)